# represent the boundary of a C1 compact manifold in R2

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a compact submanifold of $R^2$ of dimension $2$, with boundary (for instance: a compact disc in which  small disjoint compact discs have been cut off). By drawing pictures, it seems that the boundary of $M$ can be decomposed in a finite union of Jordan curves. Is there a formal proof for that?

Comment: "Let $M$ be a compact submanifold of $R^2$ of dimension $2$". Are you sure ($2$ and $2$)?